# send message to view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the controller if the condition is trues is it possible to send a message to the View sales, and display this message only if the condition Is true.

in the controller I have :

```
return RedirectToAction("sales", "Home");
```

in the View Sales I want to display the message : your order is sent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ViewBag

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{
   ViewBag.MyMessage("Hello world!!");
   return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@ViewBag.MyMessage
```

You can find the right information here

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

**Other way** could be have a field in your ViewModel and store the message you want to pass there

For Example:

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string MyString {get;set;}
   public bool MyBool {get;set;}
}
```

in **controller**

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   var myObject = new MyViewModel
   {
      MyString = "Hello world!",
      MyBool = //set value according to your need
   };
   return view();
}
```

in **view**

```
@model MyViewModel
@if(model.MyBool == true)
{
  <text>@model.MyString</text>
}
else
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks I used ViewBag